# Build option - RemappingConfigFile not available

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mdm

I am trying to integrate MDM in my android app made on Xamarin Forms using the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-xamarin . In the last step we have set the Build option to RemappingConfigFile of the added json file. But I am not getting the build option RemappingConfigFile.

Can someone please help?

Comment: "In the last step we have set the Build option to RemappingConfigFile of the added json file. But I am not getting the build option RemappingConfigFile." These two sentences contradiction in my opinion. Are you saying that you're trying to set the build action to `RemappingConfigFile`, but you cannot find this option?

Comment: I am trying to set the build action of added  "remapping-config.json" to RemappingConfigFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on your project and select "Unload project". Then right click on the project and select "Edit .scproj".

Find the `ItemGroup` part and then add this `ItemGroup`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <RemappingConfigFile Include="remapping-config.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Save the file and then right click the project and reload your project.

Comment: Thank you so much !